# How to print out a command which Gradle uses to start and spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have a little problem. My spring boot application works correctly when I start it as a Gradle 's task. Like down here.

```
 ./gradlew bootRun
```

But when I start an app as a jar like below

```
C:/"Program Files"/jdk-11/bin/java -jar build/someApp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --appId=SomeApp
```

I got in the one place segfault (Segmentation fault).

It happens only when I'm starting an app like this, not as gradle task. So I think that Gradle starts an app with some special jvm parameters (?)

It is possible to print out how Gradle start an app? I was trying to use switches like --scan, -S, -d etc but did not see any interesting things.

Comment: run a app using gradle and then in a separate command window run `wmic process list` that will give you exact command line that is used. But generally the seg fault should not happen in java. I see that you are using 11 so try to lower the version of JDK.

Comment: Works, very thx!